# Why am I getting a JSON error and how do I fix it

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, node.js

I am trying got take the value that is inserted into the first and last name fields and then take that and insert it into a MySQL database backend that I have running using restAPI. I got some help to fix the form but I am trying to find the error when I try to take the input form the form and enter it in the database

The table code is this

```
  <div class="superhero">
    <h1>Lets add our first name </h1>
    <form action="/add_user" method="post">
        <input type = "text" firstname = "firstname">
    <h1>Lets add our last name </h1>
    <form action="/add_user" method="post">
        <input type = "text" lastname = "lastname">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

Then this is taken into the nodeJS server with this command

```
app.post('/add_people', function(req, res){
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/adduser')
    .then((response)=>{
        var restlist = response.data.results;
        console.log(restlist);
// Now we will execute the results in the page named thanks
    });
});
```

Then at the end it is going to be taken to the RestAPI with that is using this route

```
@app.route('/api/adduser', methods = ['POST']) # This is a post method because the user needs to be able to add info
def adding_stuff():
    request_data = request.get_json() # Gets the info from the table and converts to JSON format
    new_fname = request_data['firstname']
    new_lname = request_data['lastname']
    conn = create_connection("", "", "", "")
    sql = "INSERT INTO restaurantusers (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('%s', '%s');" % (new_fname, new_lname) # This sql statement will then be uploaded to the databse to add a new record
    execute_query(conn, sql) # This will execute the query
    return 'Post worked'
```

Sorry if what I am asking sounds really complicated. Professor goes too fast in class and I've been trying to find out how to do this for sometime with no luck.

UDATE: I later changed the two items as suggested. The route is

```
app.post('/add_people', function(req, res){
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/adduser')
    .then((response)=>{
        var restlist = response.data.results;
        console.log(restlist);
// Now we will execute the results in the page named thanks
    });
});
```

and the form is now

```
        <form action="/add_people" method="post">
            <input type = "text" firstname = "firstname">
        <h1>Lets add our last name </h1>
            <input type = "text" lastname = "lastname">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
```

I get the error that

```
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

and also this error on the restAPI window

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and explain the problem clearly. Start by explaining the overall architecture of the system you are working on, and the steps that you take to interact with the code. It seems like you somehow have both node.js and some kind of Python framework (which one?) running on the server, and I can't guess why you have both, and have only a vague idea of how they are communicating with each other.

Comment: That said: when you write `axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/adduser')`, how exactly are you expecting that to forward the form response data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to update your form and inputs to accept user input properly by using the `value` attribute on the `<input>` so instead of

```
<input type = "text" firstname = "firstname">
<input type = "text" lastname = "lastname">
```

Do this

```
<input type="text" value="firstname">
<input type="text" value="lastname">
```

this will send the values `firstname` and `lastname` to your API.
If you need to dynamically accept user input you'll need to watch input changes using javascript and handle the form submit with it too. Check
[input value attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) and [Javascript form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript).

To send the data from your node server to your python server you'll need to update

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/adduser')
```

To

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/adduser', { first_name: req.body.firstname, last_name: req.body.last_name })
```

Because that way you're passing the form data inside req.body to your python server